# Import Match migrate to a new file

Tags: gnucash

I'm using Gnucash 4.2 on Windows 10.  For my old file I have imported transactions and pretty much all my imports have "Import Match" now.

However, when I start a new file, all the "Import Match" data is gone. The import match editor shows nothing.

Is there a way to migrate the "Import Match" data from an old file to a new file?  I really don't want to start over to specify the accounts for each transaction I import to the new file. It's painful.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Why are you starting a new file?  If you are continuing to manage the accounts for the same entity there's probably no reason to start a new file.  Is there something wrong with the old file?